# How to Draw X-Axis with Dates from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

Pre-emptive apologies for any novice mistakes made in the underlying code. I am attempting to generate a simple **line chart** with d3.js, with **dates on the x-axis** and **integer values on the y-axis**. The data is supplied by **two arrays**: `xDataGet` and `yData` from The issue I'm having is, from what I can gather, that the strings in `xDataGet` are not being properly converted to `Dates`. In tinkering with the code, I can manage to have the Y-Axis appear, but have had no such luck with the X-Axis. Could someone indicate where I'm going wrong?

```
    var margin = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
    var width = 1000 - margin[1] - margin[3]; // width
    var height = 400 - margin[0] - margin[2]; // height

    var xDataGet = [ '03/18/2014', '03/01/2014', '02/15/2014', '02/01/2014', '01/18/2014', '12/07/2013', '11/16/2013' ]


    function getDate(d) {
        formatted = d3.time.format("%m-%d-%Y")
        return formatted(new Date(d));
    }

    var xData = getDate(xDataGet)
    var yData = [ 33, 36, 42, 27, 36, 21, 18 ]

    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width])
        .domain([d3.min(xData), d3.max(xData)])
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0])
        .domain([0, d3.max(yData)]);


    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(xData); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(yData); })
        .interpolate("linear");

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + 80 + 80)
        .attr("height", height + 80 + 80)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 80 + "," + 80 + ")");

    svg.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-25,0)")
        .call(yAxis);

    svg.append("svg:path").attr("d", line);
```

Comment: In `getDate(d)` you are passing `d` as an array, in which the `Date` object does not take as a parameter. You want to use each element in the array as a `date-string`. Use a `for` loop and do: `xData[i] = getDate(xDataGet[i]);`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek could you demonstrate the loop? I tried to implement it, but I keep recieving either undefined or null values.

Comment: I would be something like: `for(data in xDataGet) xData[data] = getDate(xDataGet[data]);` Where xData is: `var xData = new Array(xDataGet.length);`.